# Show if this is integrable (defined 1 on rationals, 0 else)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, proof-writing

Define $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 1 & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$

Find $\displaystyle \underline{\int_0^1f}$ and $\displaystyle \overline{\int_0^1f}$. Is this function integrable?

I'm trying to show this using the definition of Riemann integration directly. I know that I could use the fact that the discontinuities of $f$ has measure zero so $f$ is integrable, but I'm having trouble approaching it just using more basic definitions.

Also -- unrelated -- but why are my integrals getting mushed together with their bounds?

Comment: $f$ is discontinuous everywhere... But any non-degenerate interval contains both irrationals and rationals. So then, what is the value of any upper sum? Any lower sum?

Comment: ** sorry, the rest of your comment didn't load before I responded. Not sure why. My comment is no longer relevant**

Comment: So that would give me that the lower sum is 0 and the upper sum is 1(b-a). However, that would mean that this function is not integrable. Which I find strange, as Thomae's function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Thomae's function is continuous on the irrationals though. Its set of points of discontinuity has measure zero. Your function's set of points of discontinuity has measure $1$.

Comment: Aha! Thanks, I should have seen that. God I am brain dead today... 
If you put it as an answer I'll accept it to throw some rep your way.

Comment: @Craig your integrals were getting mushed together because you were in inline math mode. If you want the full LaTeX you can add \displaystyle when you start an inline math mode block and it will resize the symbols accordingly.

Comment: It is Lebesgue integrable (and Kurzweill-Henstock integrable) but not Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\displaystyle \underline{\int_0^1 f} = 0$ and  $\displaystyle \overline{\int_0^1 f} = 1$.

This follows from the fact that every interval contains infinitely many rationals and irrationals, so we can choose our partition to contain only rationals in which case $f$ is zero on each of those partition points, or we can choose our partition to contain only irrationals in which case $f$ is one on each of those partition points.

Recall that $f$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if $\displaystyle \underline f = \overline f$.

We've shown this isn't true in our case, so we can conclude that $f$ is not Riemann-integrable.